# mat-sidenav-container always empty in dom

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a sidebar for my angular application using functionality from the `@angular/material` package.

I've tried out multiple ways to add the sidebar to by application but it remains empty/not showing up.

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>

      <a mat-list-item > Accounts </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Account </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Contacts </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Contact </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Activities </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Activity </a>
      <a mat-list-item (click)="sidenav.toggle()" href="" mat-list-item>Close</a>

    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div style="height: 88vh;">

      content
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This is the code I'm using in my html template file.

This is the resulting dom:

[image]

I have no idea why nothing is there inside the mat-sidenav-container.
I'm using angular 9 and created this project with the CLI.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` solved this problem for me.